# how to use useLocation hook in a custom file in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a separate file where I put the commonly used functions in my react project called `MyFunctions.js` . In this file, I want to use `useLocation` hook to get the current pathname + the query string of my current url. but it gives an error

```
React Hook "useLocation" is called in function "getCurrentURL" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.
```

this is my code: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wave-lijz1f?file=/src/App.js:0-441)

```
// MyFunctions.js
import useLocation from "react-router-dom";

export function getUrl() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname + location.search;
}
```

```
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import * as fn from "./MyFunctions";
import Test1 from "./components/Test1";

export default function App() {
  const a = fn.getUrl();

  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox: {a}</h1>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Test1 />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
// Test1.js
const Test1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test1;
```

Comment: if it's not a default export you may need curlies: { useLocation }

Comment: @JoeFitzsimmons I tried using curly braces but the error is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `useLocation` inside curly braces in the import, like this:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

I would recommend you to rename `getUrl` to `useGetURL` to fulfil React's hook conventions.

Additionally, you have to call `useLocation` inside a child of `<Router />`. You haven't, therefore, you will get another error: `useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`

I fixed it as follows:

```js
// App.js
import "./styles.css";
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import * as fn from "./MyFunctions";
import Test1 from "./components/Test1";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <YourNestedComponent />
    </Router>
  );
}

function YourNestedComponent() {
  const a = fn.useGetUrl();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox: {a}</h1>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Test1 />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
// MyFunctions.js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export function useGetUrl() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname + location.search;
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-orla-tbnb07

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a hook inside a function export a hook instead like this

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";

export function useGetUrl() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return location.pathname + location.search;
}
```

And import this hook inside  any component and use it like this

```
import {useGetUrl} from '[your_filename].js'
const url = useGetUrl()
```

[NOTE] You cannot call this hook directly inside JSX you have to call it on top of your component first then you can use the `url` inside your jsx, in whatever component you are using this hook make sure it is wrapped with `<Router></Router>`